# Manipulating multiple parameters in a ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

The question is not specific, but not entirely non-specific.

Please suggest how to  compactly re-code and  generalize ParametricPlot command to push in one more parameter `w` in  *Manipulate* mode.

That is, how can I extend as function of function or by any other means conversion from:

```
ParametricPlot[{f[u, v], g[u, v]}, {u, umin, umax}, {v, vmin, vmax}]
```

to

```
ParamManipulatePlot[{f[u, v, w], g[u, v, w]}, 
  {u, umin, umax}, {v, vmin, vmax}, {w, wmin, wmax}]
```

***Either*** one slider for any one of three parameters {u, v, w} should be provided for variation/perturbation or ***alternatively*** three sliders for all three parameters {u, v, w} for variation/perturbation.

In the last option I for one opine it is not about the technique of just doing it, but about demonstration of wider science of mathematical thought. Perhaps in tune with NKS philosophy, regarding multiple parameter embedments even if immersion is just in the minimum visible 2D plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{w Sin[u + v + y], z Cos[(u + v) x]}, 
              {u, 0,  2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
          {{w, .5}, 0, 1}, {{z, .5}, 0, 1}, {{x, .5}, 0, 1}, {{y, Pi}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]