# manipulate with Plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Facing problem with using manipulate along with Plot. Below is the function call where I have only one parameter to change, hence plot is not allowing. Searched for various options but not able to achieve manipulation

```
curve = Manipulate[ParametricPlot[abc[b, n, 0, t], {t, 0.7, 1.2},PlotStyle -> 
{Thick}], {{t, 0, "max"}, 0, 1}];
```

Need to manipulate as per t value. Not able to get the correct syntax.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Will do so :) can you help me in this

Comment: Have a look here [Initial Values and Labels](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html#498667553)

Comment: Including the definition of `abc` would be nice…

Comment: Have you seen [Manipulating multiple parameters in a ParametricPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60822/manipulating-multiple-parameters-in-a-parametricplot)?

Comment: abc is recursive de Casteljau algorithm

Comment: I saw both the links you provided, thanks for that. My problem here is I only have one parameter that is 't' which needs to be manipulated while as I see in examples for Parametric Plot, they have one parameter fixed and other changing which is manipulated. Is there some way to achieve so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate the t of your plot function.

Try this

```
curve = Manipulate[ParametricPlot[abc[b, n, 0, t], {t, tStart, tStart + tPlus}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thick}], {{tStart, 0.7, "start"}, 0, 
1}, {{tPlus, 0.5, "plus"}, 0, 1}];
```

Comment: throws error as 
`ParametricPlot::plld: "Endpoints for t in {t,FE`tStart$$2779,FE`tStart$$2779+FE`tPlus$$2779} must have distinct machine-precision numerical values. "`

Comment: Yes, you shold not try to use an exact zero. Try the edited one, where the starting values aren't zero.

Comment: `$MachineEpsilon` is handy for that sort of thing.